# PHP: Image Croper / Resizer

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, php-gd

I'm working on a website that has many tiled images using JQuery's Masonry plugin.  The tiles are all uniform in size, but the images contained within them can be a number of sizes.

I was wondering if there's a good recommendation for a PHP plugin / script that can take an incoming image of any size, and do whatever is required to fit in a certain sized box (have automatically resize, crop, insert black space, etc.)

EDIT:

Thanks for the Php options.  is there anything in the JQuery realm too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script would fit your need as well :

http://www.phpcodester.com/2011/01/php-function-to-resize-image-to-fit-in-a-standard-box-without-distortion/

If you need to modify something, php's image functions are always named `imagesomething($resource,x,y,etc.)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that.  is there anything as far as JQuery plugins as well?

Comment: If you want a client side approach, there is jquery.resizecrop. It resizes then crops the image to make it fit in a specific width / height. http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at TimThumb: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/